# Formatting issue

Tags: bash, shell

I have a small script like below, where output gets highlighted (in red,yellow etc) on screen if there an issue

```
normal=$(tput sgr0)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)

df -h >/dev/null 2>&1 &
xx_pid=$!
sleep 3
if [ `ps -ef| grep $xx_pid | grep -v grep | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
kill $xx_pid > /dev/null 2>&1
 printf "%-70s %s\n" "${red}df -h response : "  "  ......... taking more  than 30 Seconds to complete, exiting script${normal}" | tee -a $log
 exit
else
 printf "%-70s %s\n" "df -h response : "  " ......... NORMAL (Completed in  less than 30sec)" | tee -a $log
 fi
```

But in logfile I am seeing junk characters as below ([31m and (B[m )

```
[31mdf -h response :                    ......... taking more than 30 Seconds to complete, exiting script(B[m
```

Is there any way to avoid those junk characters without writing into log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `tee`: you can assign your message to a variable and `printf` *that* using colors, and *then* append the message to the logfile:

```
 msg=$(printf "%-70s %s" "df -h response : "  " ......... NORMAL (Completed in >
 printf "%s%s%s\n" "${red}" "$msg" "${normal}"
 printf "%s\n" "$msg" >>$log
```

rather than

```
 printf "%-70s %s\n" "${red}df -h response : "  "  ......... taking more  than 30 Seconds to complete, exiting script${normal}" | tee -a $log
```

The problem with `tee` is that it can only write to the standard output.  You *could* do something with your script to redirect the standard output separately, but it is cumbersome:

```
 ( printf "%-70s %s\n" "df -h response : "  "  ......... taking more  than 30 Seconds to complete, exiting script" | tee -a $log ) | sed -e "s/^/${red}/" -e "s/$/${normal}/"
```

Comment: There are several other parts of code using tee as i need to display output on screen and append to log. Another other method where I can still use tee ?

Comment: You need to realize that the "junk" characters that you're seeing in the log are the codes needed for color output on the terminal. So no, you cannot use tee to output the same lines to logfile and terminal, you will need to write different entries to those destinations.